# (1054, "Unknown column 'leçon_lesson.subject_id' in 'field list'")

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views

i have been making some changes on my model 'lesson' and suddenly i couldn't use my model on my django website with MySql data base.
when i try to use it  on a view i got this error
(1054, "Unknown column 'leçon_lesson.subject_id' in 'field list'")
the commands makemigrations and migrate works fine but this error occurs when using the model only
this is the model.py

```
    from django.db import models
from .validators import *

from scolarité.models.level import Level
from scolarité.models.subject import Subject

class Lesson(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapiter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lesson = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vacations = models.IntegerField()
    link = models.URLField(max_length=700,null=True,blank=True)
    remarques = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    state = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lesson
```

views.py

```
#=========================== view lessons =====================
@login_required  #use this to make the view accessible for logged in users only
def view_lessons_list(request,subject_id):
    request.session['subject_id']= subject_id                       #assign subject id value to session
    level = Level.objects.get(id=request.session['level_id'])       #getting the level model 
    subject = Subject.objects.get(id=request.session['subject_id']) #getting the subject model 

    lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(subject=subject ,level=level)   #filtering the lesson based on the chosen level and subject
    context={'lessons':lessons,}
    return render(request,'leçon/view_lessons_list.html',context)
```

the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\leçon\views.py", line 25, in view_lessons_list
    return render(request,'leçon/view_lessons_list.html',context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 173, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1102, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\YAHYA-PC\Desktop\CourseCode\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'leçon_lesson.subject_id' in 'field list'")
[11/Oct/2020 20:36:35] "GET /le%C3%A7on/view_lessons_list/18/ HTTP/1.1" 500 299785
```

i have been trying deleting the migration files and and different youtube tutorials but nothing seems to work for me i keep getting different database errors and start all over again with this error
is there any solution or fix for this matter ?it's really frustrating and letting me down

Comment: Was the change related to the `subject` field? Did you by any chance run a manual migration?

Comment: yes i was changing the name for the subject field

Comment: Looks like your migration didn't run properly. The field name didn't update in the DB. It still has the old name. You can verify that by querying the columns of the table in MySQL.

Comment: i keep getting this problem when ever i put a new name it raturns the same error with the new name is this have somthing to do with it ?

Comment: can you run `python manage.py showmigrations` and post the result?

Comment: thank you for your help,i just found out a solution not the most efficient but it works i just created a new app with different name and moved all the models and views to it

Answer (score 0):

i just found out a solution not the most efficient but it works i just created a new app with different name and moved all the models and views to it and run makemigrations and migrate and that's it